# RxJava Bigger Application Example / How do multiple Observable's fit

Tags: rx-java

currently I'm starting out with observable's, however Currently I'm stuck with something..

At the moment I have a main class these one will call a Observable file watcher, so far so good. That works.

so something like that:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
     Observable<String> myObservable = observable();
     // Buffer on Backpressure since I load every old file/directory, too
     Subscription subscription = observable.onBackpressureBuffer() 
        .subscribe(subscriber -> {

        })
    ... // Code that stop the program from stopping
}
```

So that's what I have however know I want to have some other Observable's something like
`OfficeObservable` or `PdfObservable`. Which will be used when the file has a extension of `.pdf` it will use the PdfObservable. And if it has something like `.docx` it should call the OfficeObservable. However how could I attach that to a bigger program. Especially since that won't be the last observable's I want to use.

Could I just chain them together inside the subscribe method or flatMap over them and let all of them return the same interface?
I'm stuck on how to get a bigger Application out of RxJava.

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could expose your specialised (and FileObservable) like this:

```
Observable<String> fileObservable;

private void init(){ // called from constructor or some other init'ish method
  //init your fileObservable
}    

public Observable<String> getFileObservable(){
  return fileObservable;  
}
public Observable<String> getPdfFileObservable(){
  return fileObservable.filter(name -> name.endsWith(".pdf"))
}
```

It strongly depends on what you want to do, if you want to add a `cache()` to your fileObservable or put other helpful Observable operators in.